# Merge html-tag to other-tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this method:

```
 while (created < 2)
        {
      var tb = new TagBuilder("input");
            tb.MergeAttribute("id", model.QuestionId);
            tb.MergeAttribute("name", model.QuestionId);
            tb.MergeAttribute("type", "radio");
            if (model.Disabled == true)
            {
                tb.MergeAttribute("Disabled", model.Disabled.ToString());
            }
            tb.MergeAttributes(GetHtmlAttributes(model.HtmlAttributes));
            tb.AddCssClass("form-field");
            var innerText = created % 2 == 0 ? "Kvinna" : "Man";
            tb.MergeAttribute("value", innerText);
            sb.Append(tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
            var spanBuilder = new TagBuilder("span");
            spanBuilder.SetInnerText(innerText);

   This code ---> var spanBuilders = new TagBuilder("span");
            spanBuilders.MergeAttribute("id", model.QuestionId + "radio");
            spanBuilders.MergeAttribute(spanBuilder.ToString((TagRenderMode.Normal)));<--- 

            sb.Append(spanBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

What i want to do is in some way merge the span-tag spanbuilder and put it into another tag. The while-loop is goint through twice so it will create two span-tags of spanbuilder and i would like them booth to be inside another span-tag. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a DocFragment for the Span Tag and then attach that to the parent.
I would recommend you use a XMLDocument or XDocument to do this.
See [X Document link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1450787.aspx/1)